# Discrepancy between call to statvfs and df command

Tags: linux, file

When I use the statvfs command on a Linux machine to get the available free space on a mounted file system, the number I get is slightly different than what is reported by df.

For example, one on machine I have with a 500G hard drive, I get the following output from df:

```
# df --block-size=1 --no-sync
Filesystem           1B-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0             492256247808 3422584832 463828406272   1% /
tmpfs                2025721856         0 2025721856   0% /lib/init/rw
varrun               2025721856    114688 2025607168   1% /var/run
varlock              2025721856      4096 2025717760   1% /var/lock
udev                 2025721856    147456 2025574400   1% /dev
tmpfs                2025721856     94208 2025627648   1% /dev/shm
```

A call to statvfs gives me a block size of 4096 and 119344155 free blocks, so that there should be 488,833,658,880 bytes free.  Yet, df reports there are 463,828,406,272 bytes free.  Why is there a discrepancy here?

Answer (score 11):

Since your discrepancy is close to 5% [1], which is the default percentage allocated for root, there is a possibility that you compare the df result with the ->f_bfree of statvfs and 
not with ->f_bavail, which is what df uses.

[1]: (488833658880 -  463828406272)/492256247808  = 0.0508

Comment: Ahh...I see.  Yes, using f_bavail the numbers are the same.  Thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: I am finding a discrepancy in calculating percentages of free. When I calculate (f_bavail * 100.0) / f_blocks" - I expect to have (100 - use percentage from df). However - this is out by 4%. The error is further out if I use f_bfree.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
int main(){
    struct statvfs stat;
    int a=statvfs("/",&stat);
    printf("total free disk space of the partition: %d GB \n",(stat.f_bavail)*8/2097152);
    //512 is 2^9 - one half of a kilobyte. 
    //A kilobyte is 2^10. A megabyte is 2^20. A gigabyte is 2^30. A terabyte
    //is 2^40. And so on. The common computer units go up by 10's of powers
    //of 2 like that.
    //So you need to divide by 2^(30-9) == 2^21 == 2097152 to get gigabytes.
    //And multiply by 8 because 1 byte=8bit
    return 0;
}
```

I do in this form because I prefer the outcome in Gb, but you can modify the units changing the exponent.And is true the first answer, as you can see, I use that too

Answer (score 0):

Note that under Linux, `df` uses `stat` on the device file, not `statvfs`; cf [the coreutils source](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/df.c).

However, the basic principle above applies. As to why `df` is so much faster and whether there are any shortcuts available for `du`....

The filesystem entry for any specific folder contains information about that folder only: how much space is allocated for the folder itself, and how space is allocated for the file system entries for the files and folders in that folder - it does not contain the total space occupied by that folder and all of its subfolders.

To get that information, `du` has to list all of the folders in the original folder, all of their folders, and so on, totalling as it goes.

So `du` will return very quickly for a folder without subfolders, and ever more slowly for folders with increasing numbers of subfolders.

Contrast that with `df`, with a call to `stat(3)` against a device file, or with a call to `statfs(2)` or `statvfs(3)` against any file on a device, etc., all of which return information about the specific device/filesystem immediately.

`du` can only rival the speed of `df` in the case of being called against a single file, where both `du` and `df` are making a single system call and doing very little math.